# How to plot multiple CSV files as a boxplot on the same plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I have 13 different saved CSV files in a folder and each file contains just one column of data (i previously saved these separately from a larger dataset using python having calculated what I needed to), I would like to plot each of these files as 13 different boxplots on the same plot.

I am quite new to python and I'm familiar with matplotlib, so far I know how to plot each of these files individually but of course, I would like them to be plotted next to each other so I can better compare and visualise my data.
here are two of my plots:
using`plt.boxplot(af,meanline=True,showmeans=True)`

[boxplot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGtRk.png)
[boxplot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDa0D.png)

this is how I named/saved my files (just 2 of them here)

```
af=numpy.loadtxt(fname='af_river.csv.')
am=numpy.loadtxt(fname='am_river.csv.')
```

but I don't know where to go from here, do I/is there a way to create a loop which goes through each of these files separately and plots them next to each other?

Comment: look at `numpy.stack`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
plt.boxplot([af,am],meanline=True,showmeans=True)
```

This will plot all the files in the same plot

Comment: thank you so much, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @user220822 well I suppose you should accept the answer then, so the question gets marked as answered and might be helpful for others in the future :)